# C# MongoDB set different Id representation for derived classes

Tags: c#, mongodb

it's possible to change representation of inherited Id field from **BsonType.ObjectId** to **BsonType.String**?

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass : BaseClass
{
}
```

I tried this approach, but it doesn't work.

```
BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<BaseClass>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    var id = cm.GetMemberMap(c => c.Id);
    cm.SetIdMember(id);
    cm.IdMemberMap.SetRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId);
});

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyClass>(cm =>
{
    cm.AutoMap();
    var idMember = cm.IdMemberMap; // idMember is null
    idMember.SetRepresentation(BsonType.String);
});
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. Derived classes cannot change the representation of fields in their base classes. Derived classes do of course have full control over how they want *their* fields to be serialized.